# Is there an automatic way to remove nodes from an Azure Batch pool as their associated tasks completes?

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have an Azure Batch job where each node has a single task to run.  Some of the tasks finish quickly, some run for much longer.  I am using an auto-pool with around 100 nodes, so I want to give back the unneeded nodes ASAP.

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this pattern of node usage, or should I use auto-scaling where I set the number of dedicated/low-pri nodes to the number of pending tasks?  If I do use auto-scaling, will Azure Batch always remove the idle nodes first?  I don't want the active nodes to be disturbed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the auto scaling rules, this scenario is exactly what they're for. There is an option to only remove the node once it's tasks are complete - see NodeDeallocationOption. Note that the minimum autoscale rule evaluation interval is 5 minutes so you will have a slight delay between adding your tasks and the scaling to kick in.

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling for some of the autoscale formula.

Comment: On minor correction, the scale operation is not guaranteed to only target idle nodes. There is an option which can be set (in some of the examples) of `$NodeDeallocationOption = taskcompletion` which does give the guarantee that if a node which is not idle is targeted, no work will be disturbed.

Comment: I tried the formula "$TargetLowPriorityNodes = max(0, $PendingTasks.GetSample(1)); $NodeDeallocationOption = taskcompletion;", but pool is initially sized at "0" instead of the number of pending tasks, which is "70".  When I manually resized and reapplied the formula thru Batch Explorer, it then started the resize.  Do I need to further tweak the above formula to make it work correctly for the initial evaluation?

Comment: Note: after 15 minutes (default auto scale formula eval interval), it evaluates the number of pending tasks correctly.  I would like to avoid this 15 minute initial delay, if possible.  Thanks.